# How do I apply a complex conditional change across multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data frames that are generated off of different scripts. I want to use one to modify the other based on a condition that I have to check for each column.

DF1

```
dgCondition a_1000  a_1001  a_1010  a_1011
1   0   0   0   0
2   0   1   1   1
3   1   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   0
5   1   0   0   1
6   0   0   1   0
7   0   0   0   1
8   1   0   1   0
9   0   0   0   0
```

DF2

```
dgCondition a_1000  a_1001  a_1010  a_1011
1   1   1   0   0
2   0   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   1
5   1   1   1   0
7   1   1   0   0
7   1   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
7   0   1   0   1
4   0   1   0   1
4   0   1   0   1
4   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   1   0
4   1   1   0   1
6   1   1   0   1
6   1   1   0   0
6   0   0   1   0
6   0   0   1   0
```

This code performs what I want to do for a single case, but I don't know how to get that to work for all subsequent columns. I have many to check, and the names and number of columns will vary based one the data used by scripts that generate the dataframes above.

```
testVect <- DF1 %>% filter(a_1000 == 1)
testVect <- testVect %>% select(-contains("a_"))

DF2 <- DF2 %>% mutate(aDG_1000 = (a_1000 == 1 & dgCondition %in% testVect$dgCondition)*1)
```

The lines above filter `DF1$dgCondition` so that only the rows where `a_1000 == 1` remain, so in that case 3,5, 8. Then I set `a_1000` to 0 everywhere except where it was already set to 1 and one of the conditions matches one in `testVect`. So the result for `a_1000` in `DF2` is a new column with:

```
dgCondition aDG_1000
1   0
2   0
1   0
5   1
7   0
7   0
7   0
1   0
7   0
4   0
4   0
4   0
4   0
4   0
6   0
6   0
6   0
6   0
```

I have tried building a for loop to iterate through each column, but have not had any luck. I have been researching do.call with lapply as a possibility too. But I haven't had any luck with that yet either. I feel like I am missing something that would make this work, so I thought would ask the experts.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the example: you probably mean `dgCondition %in% testVect$dgCondition` and not `%in% DF1$dgCondition`

Comment: ah you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R approach :

```
result <- cbind(df2[1], mapply(function(x, y) {
              as.integer(df2$dgCondition %in% x & y == 1)
          }, lapply(df1[-1], function(x) df1$dgCondition[x == 1]), df2[-1]))
result
#   dgCondition a_1000 a_1001 a_1010 a_1011
#1            1      0      0      0      0
#2            2      0      1      1      1
#3            1      0      0      0      0
#4            5      1      0      0      0
#5            7      0      0      0      0
#6            7      0      0      0      0
#7            7      0      0      0      0
#8            1      0      0      0      0
#9            7      0      0      0      1
#10           4      0      0      0      0
#11           4      0      0      0      0
#12           4      0      0      0      0
#13           4      0      0      0      0
#14           4      0      0      0      0
#15           6      0      0      0      0
#16           6      0      0      0      0
#17           6      0      0      1      0
#18           6      0      0      1      0
```

`lapply(df1[-1], function(x) df1$dgCondition[x == 1])` returns `dgCondition` values in each column where the value is 1. These values along with `df2` we pass in `mapply` and assign 1 if `dgCondition` of `df1` is present in `df2` and also it's `y` value is 1.

Comment: awesome. Works great. I haven't used the `lapply` and `mapply` yet and it looks like I am going to have to read up on them. One thing I am not clear on is why use -1 in `[ ]` ?

Comment: It is to ignore the first column in both the dataframes which is `dgCondition`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach by pivoting everything in long format.

```r
library(tidyverse)
DF1 <- read.table(text="dgCondition a_1000  a_1001  a_1010  a_1011
1   0   0   0   0
2   0   1   1   1
3   1   0   1   0
4   0   0   0   0
5   1   0   0   1
6   0   0   1   0
7   0   0   0   1
8   1   0   1   0
9   0   0   0   0", header=TRUE)


DF2 <- read.table(text="dgCondition a_1000  a_1001  a_1010  a_1011
1   1   1   0   0
2   0   1   1   1
1   0   0   1   1
5   1   1   1   0
7   1   1   0   0
7   1   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
7   0   1   0   1
4   0   1   0   1
4   0   1   0   1
4   0   0   1   0
4   0   0   1   0
4   1   1   0   1
6   1   1   0   1
6   1   1   0   0
6   0   0   1   0
6   0   0   1   0", header=TRUE)


testVect <- DF1 %>% filter(a_1000 == 1)
testVect <- testVect %>% select(-contains("a_"))

DF2bis <- DF2 %>% mutate(aDG_1000 = (a_1000 == 1 & (dgCondition %in% testVect$dgCondition))*1)
```

First, let's reformulate DF1 in a more practical way:

```
conds_for_DF1 <- pivot_longer(DF1,
                            starts_with("a_"),
                            names_to = "a_xxx") %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  group_by(a_xxx) %>%
  summarize(dgConds_DF1 = list(dgCondition),
            dgConds_readable = paste(dgCondition, collapse=", "))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

conds_for_DF1
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   a_xxx  dgConds_DF1 dgConds_readable
#>   <chr>  <list>      <chr>           
#> 1 a_1000 <int [3]>   3, 5, 8         
#> 2 a_1001 <int [1]>   2               
#> 3 a_1010 <int [4]>   2, 3, 6, 8      
#> 4 a_1011 <int [3]>   2, 5, 7
```

Note that I will use the column `dgConds_DF1`, I just added a character version `dgConds_readable` to visualize what's happening.

Then, we can pivot DF2 in a longer format, and simply `join` it with our transformed DF1. That way, each row has a single dgCondition and a_xxx, we can then simply verify the conditions separately.

```
pivot_longer(DF2,
             starts_with("a_"),
             names_to = "a_xxx") %>%
  left_join(conds_for_DF1, by= "a_xxx") %>%
  mutate(dgCond_in_DF1 = map2_lgl(dgCondition, dgConds_DF1, ~ .x %in% .y),
         aDG_xxx = value * dgCond_in_DF1)
#> # A tibble: 72 x 7
#>    dgCondition a_xxx  value dgConds_DF1 dgConds_readable dgCond_in_DF1 aDG_xxx
#>          <int> <chr>  <int> <list>      <chr>            <lgl>           <int>
#>  1           1 a_1000     1 <int [3]>   3, 5, 8          FALSE               0
#>  2           1 a_1001     1 <int [1]>   2                FALSE               0
#>  3           1 a_1010     0 <int [4]>   2, 3, 6, 8       FALSE               0
#>  4           1 a_1011     0 <int [3]>   2, 5, 7          FALSE               0
#>  5           2 a_1000     0 <int [3]>   3, 5, 8          FALSE               0
#>  6           2 a_1001     1 <int [1]>   2                TRUE                1
#>  7           2 a_1010     1 <int [4]>   2, 3, 6, 8       TRUE                1
#>  8           2 a_1011     1 <int [3]>   2, 5, 7          TRUE                1
#>  9           1 a_1000     0 <int [3]>   3, 5, 8          FALSE               0
#> 10           1 a_1001     0 <int [1]>   2                FALSE               0
#> # ... with 62 more rows
```

Finally, if you want to recover the initial format with a_xxx as separate columns, you just need to `pivot_wider`. There is a twist though, since several rows of DF2 have the same dgCondition, we need a separate row ID to recover them:

```
DF2 %>%
  mutate(row_id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("a_"),
               names_to = "a_xxx") %>%
  left_join(conds_for_DF1, by= "a_xxx") %>%
  mutate(dgCond_in_DF1 = map2_lgl(dgCondition, dgConds_DF1, ~ .x %in% .y),
         aDG_xxx = value * dgCond_in_DF1) %>%
  select(row_id, dgCondition, a_xxx, aDG_xxx) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "a_xxx",
              values_from = "aDG_xxx") %>%
  select(-row_id)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 5
#>    dgCondition a_1000 a_1001 a_1010 a_1011
#>          <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#>  1           1      0      0      0      0
#>  2           2      0      1      1      1
#>  3           1      0      0      0      0
#>  4           5      1      0      0      0
#>  5           7      0      0      0      0
#>  6           7      0      0      0      0
#>  7           7      0      0      0      0
#>  8           1      0      0      0      0
#>  9           7      0      0      0      1
#> 10           4      0      0      0      0
#> 11           4      0      0      0      0
#> 12           4      0      0      0      0
#> 13           4      0      0      0      0
#> 14           4      0      0      0      0
#> 15           6      0      0      0      0
#> 16           6      0      0      0      0
#> 17           6      0      0      1      0
#> 18           6      0      0      1      0
```